# Linq query stage in a process

Tags: c#, linq

My models are - 
employee

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string GivenName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeAudit> EmployeeAudits { get; set; }

}
```

and employee audit

```
public class EmployeeAudit
 {
    public int EmployeeAuditId { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string AuditCode { get; set; }

    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

so i will have Employees that will have many EmployeeAudits as so -

employee

id-----name

1------bob

2------jim

3------sheila


audit

empid---auditcode-----------------datecreated

1---------created---------------------13/12/12

2---------created---------------------13/12/12

3---------created---------------------13/12/12

2---------SubmittedToHR-----------13/12/12

3---------SubmittedToHR-----------13/12/12

3---------PassedForVerification---13/12/12

The audits represents a certain stage in a process, how do i query using linq to show where
in the process an employee is at.

for example i want to show all employees that are at SubmittedToHr but have been Created and not PassedForVerification.

Comment: So, what is your question here?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will return all employees, which have last audit code equal to SubmittedToHR (assume audit code could change only from created > SubmittedToHR > PassedForVerification):

```
var query = from e in context.Employees
            join ea in context.EmployeeAudit 
                 on e.EmployeeId equals ea.EmployeeId into g
            where g.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateCreated)
                   .FirstOrDefault().AuditCode == "SubmittedToHR"
            select e;
```

Comment: Thanks Lazyberezovsky for the reply.

Comment: i will try this out and let you know how i get on. I'm new to the whole .net/mvc/c#/linq scene so still trying to find my feet.

Comment: @user1903548 no problem. Is it what you need? If it is audit code assignment is not consecutive then query should be changed to set additional condition.

Comment: yea it looks as though this is what i need. Gonna set up some data in my app and try it out.

Comment: no luck with this i am afraid as Linq to entities does not support LastOrDefault. Any ideas

Comment: @user1903548 sorry, use descending sorting and FirstOrDefault instead, I've updated sample

Comment: yes this works now, however i don't know if it is returning the correct results, testing will confirm. Cheers.